# boost::signals2::signal gives wrong output?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

I'm new to boost library, while practicing an example on bind, i wrote the  following code. But, it seems like the 'res' is computed properly but, the correct result is not transmitted back to the signal. Kindly help, what is wrong in the following snippet.
*The code was compiled and run on http://cpp.sh/*

```
#include <iostream>
#include<boost/signals2.hpp>

using namespace std;
class MathObject{
public:
    int AddOps(int op1, int op2);
};

int MathObject::AddOps(int op1, int op2){
    int res = op1 + op2;
    cout << "Result of AddOps: " << res << endl;
    return res;
}

int main(void){
    MathObject mObj;
    boost::signals2::signal<int(int)> incrementer;
    incrementer.connect(boost::bind(&MathObject::AddOps, &mObj, 1, _1));
    boost::signals2::signal<int(int)> doubler;
    doubler.connect(boost::bind(&MathObject::AddOps, &mObj, _1, _1));
    cout << "Incrementer of 5" << incrementer(5) << endl;
    cout << "Doubler of 5" << doubler(5) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Result of AddOps: 6
Incrementer of 51
Result of AddOps: 10
Doubler of 51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a signal is called, it may or may not have any handlers connected to it. Therefore it may or may not produce a result. The default behaviour is to return the result of the last-connected handler, if any; or to return a value indicating "no result". Thus the return value of `incrementer(5)` and `doubler(5)` is not an `int`, but rather a `boost::optional<int>`.

This leads to the output that you observe because a `boost::optional<int>` can be implicitly converted to `bool`, which is then converted to an output of `1` or `0`.

You need to first check that a result is present, and then get the result out of the `boost::optional<int>` that is returned:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<boost/signals2.hpp>

using namespace std;
class MathObject{
public:
    int AddOps(int op1, int op2);
};

int MathObject::AddOps(int op1, int op2){
    int res = op1 + op2;
    cout << "Result of AddOps: " << res << endl;
    return res;
}

int main(void){
    MathObject mObj;
    boost::signals2::signal<int(int)> incrementer;
    incrementer.connect(boost::bind(&MathObject::AddOps, &mObj, 1, _1));
    boost::signals2::signal<int(int)> doubler;
    doubler.connect(boost::bind(&MathObject::AddOps, &mObj, _1, _1));
    boost::optional<int> incremented = incrementer(5);
    if (incremented) {
        cout << "Incrementer of 5: " << *incremented << endl;
    }
    boost::optional<int> doubled = doubler(5);
    if (doubled) {
        cout << "Doubler of 5: " << *doubled << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp204811928) of `boost::signals2`, by default it returns the value returned by the last signal executed. But it's not a plain value - it's wrapped in `boost::optional` because there might be no signals connected to the slot and there's no reasonable value to return.

`boost::optional` is convertible to bool and that's what happens when you output it - it outputs `1` which means it *does* have a value. If instead you say `cout << incrementer(5).get()` you will get your expected output in your case.